# MySQL - Adding varchar as a foreign key

Tags: mysql, indexing, foreign-keys

I'm trying to add a varchar value as a Foreign Key.

I have tried to add a KEY within the Password_Encryption table, but that wasn't working. Then I tried creating an INDEX and that wasn't working either.

The error I get is "Error Code: 1215. Cannot add foreign key constraint".

I am aware that the comma in Password_Encryption's PRIMARY KEY line would cause an error.

The tables I have relating to this are

```
CREATE TABLE Login (
login_id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
login_date DATE NOT NULL,
customer_id INT DEFAULT 0,
business_id INT DEFAULT 0,
password_entered VARCHAR(16) DEFAULT 'password',  
password_encryption VARCHAR(20),
PRIMARY KEY (login_id, login_date)
);

CREATE TABLE Password_Encryption (
encryption_id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
login_id INT NOT NULL,
password_encryption VARCHAR(20),  
password_saved VARCHAR(16) NOT NULL,
is_valid ENUM('false','true') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'false',
/*KEY pw_enc (password_encryption),*/
PRIMARY KEY (encryption_id),
/*CONSTRAINT pw_enc FOREIGN KEY (password_encryption) REFERENCES Login 
(password_encryption)*/
);

CREATE INDEX pw_enc ON Password_Encryption(password_encryption);

ALTER TABLE Password_Encryption
ADD CONSTRAINT pw_enc FOREIGN KEY (password_encryption) REFERENCES Login (password_encryption);
```

Comment: I've also looked at other answers on Stack Overflow. I have tried them to the best of my abilities and I still can't get it to work.

Comment: Please describe the relation between the two tables.

Comment: The password_encryption variable in the Password_Encryption table is a foreign key taken from the Login table with the same named variable. I don't know the code for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get a more detailed error message by running `SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS\G` and looking at the `LATEST FOREIGN KEY ERROR` section.

In your case, you need to create an index on the parent column (`Login.password_encryption`) in order to create a foreign key constraint.

Comment: @RickJames true, it doesn't have to be unique. I'll update my answer.